# DB2 SYSIBM.SYSTABLES vs SYSCAT.TABLES

Tags: sql, db2

I'm using DB2 v9 LUW. I was wondering what the difference is between querying

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
```

Is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SYSIBM.SYSTABLES is the system catalog table, while SYSCAT.TABLES is a system catalog view. It depends of what you need, but you may use SYSIBM.SYSTABLES more often.

Comment: It ti s recommended that you perform your select against the syscat schema. Not directly the sysibm schema. Also, sysibm is the internal represntation, syscat is more standard and it does not change a lot between different versions

Comment: @AngocA Not all installations of DB2 have the syscat schema, so not all of us can follow that recommendation.

Comment: AFAIK, Syscat.table exists in all versions of db2 for LUW since version 8.2 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html Which installation of Db2 are you talking about?

Comment: There is no syscat for db2 running on top of z os.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of DB2 you are working on.  DB2 LUW version has the SYSCAT catalog views.  DB2 zOS only has the SYSIBM schema catalog tables.